# Python Tkinter error object has no attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

So I am making a program similar to the arcade games. I want the lableGuess to appear in the toplevel window after clicking the frame but it gives me this error:

AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'window'

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import time

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        master.title("Arcade Games")
        master.geometry("800x600+560+240")

        b = Button(self, text="Guess the number", command=self.new_window)
        b.pack(side="top")
        self.customFont = font.Font(master, font="Heraldica", size=12)

        self.guess_number()

    def new_window(self):

        id = "Welcome to the 'Guess your number' game!\nAll you need to do is follow the steps\nand I will guess your number!\n\nClick anywhere to start!"
        self.window = Toplevel(self.master)
        frame = Frame(self.window)
        frame.bind("<Button-1>", self.guess_number)
        frame.pack()
        self.window.title("Guess the number")
        self.window.geometry("400x300+710+390")
        label = Label(self.window, text=id, font=self.customFont)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", padx=20, pady=20)

    def guess_number(self):


        labelGuess = Label(self.window, text="Pick a number between 1 and 10", font=self.customFont)
        time.sleep(2)
        labelGuess.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=20, pady=20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    view = Window(root)
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your initial call to `guess_number` in your initializer method is probably being invoked before you press the button and trigger the `new_window` event callback. In `guess_number` you're trying to pass `self.window` as an argument to `Label()` but it would be undefined at that time.

Comment: not "probably" -- "definitely". It's right there in the `__init__`: `self.guess_number()`

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you should never create a new attribute out of the `__init__` method.

That said, [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849425/mike) pointed the trouble’s reason: you created the window object inside the `new_window` method, but did not called it.

You must call `new_window` before call `guess_number` – or call one inside other.

I suggest that you set `window` to `None` and call `new_window` inside `__init__` method, then (after that) call `guess_number`.